# Determine $C^{\circ}$ explicity in terms of $A$ and $b$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If $C \subseteq E$ is a closed convex set define
$$C^{\circ}=\bigcap_{x\in C}\{u \in E: \langle u,x\rangle\leq 1\}$$
Determine $C^{o}$ if $C= \{x: Ax \leq b\}$

### Solution so far:

$C^{o}=\bigcap_{x\in C}\{u \in E: \langle u,x\rangle\leq 1\}=\{u \in E: \langle u,x\rangle\leq 1 \> \forall x \in C\}=\{u \in E: \langle u,x\rangle\leq 1 \>with\> Ax\leq b\}$

Comment: Im not sure if am doing this right.

Comment: Yes, you're right to say that $C^\circ = \{u \in E: \langle u,x\rangle\leq 1 \> \forall x \in C\}$. If the $1$ were replaced by $0$, then $C^\circ$ would simply be the normal cone to $C$ at the origin.